# Reset Distinct after Buffer

Tags: c#, system.reactive

So I have this stream of strings like this:

```
ABA        ABCA
+--------+-------+ 
0        1       2 s
```

I would like to get the distinct values, buffer them for a second and then do this all over again. So I would like to have 2 sets of data given the diagram above:

AB and ABC

I started with this:

```
void Main()
{
    var subject = new Subject<string>();

    var subscription = subject 
    .Distinct()
    .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    .Subscribe(eg => 
        {
            eg.Dump();
        }
    );

    subject.OnNext("A");
    subject.OnNext("B");
    subject.OnNext("A");

    Console.ReadLine();

    subject.OnNext("A");
    subject.OnNext("B");
    subject.OnNext("C");
    subject.OnNext("A");

    Console.ReadLine();

    subscription.Dispose();
}
```

but this outputs AB before I enter a line at the first `Console.ReadLine()` and then C after that.

What I want is to reset the Distinct() operator after each buffer period. Is that possible?

Of course I can do this and have it working:

```
var subscription = subject 
   .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
   .Select(s => s.Distinct())
   .Subscribe(eg => 
    {
        eg.Dump();
    });
```

But I wondered whether it can be done using Rx operators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution you have at the end should work just fine. If you want to stay in Rx land with `IObservable`, you should switch to the [`Window`](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/17_SequencesOfCoincidence.html#Window) operator:

```
var subscription = subject
    .Window(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    .Select(o => o.Distinct())
    .Merge()
    .Subscribe(eg =>
        {
            eg.Dump();
        });
```

Comment: Thanks. I was already playing using  `GroupBy()` but that didn't work out as nice as this one.